# Having dificulty to figure out event and other variables in binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

A company is selling 105 tickets to a plane that has 98 seats because only 85% of the buyers actually take the flight. What is the probability that even taking this approach 3 seats will be unused?

For me the sucess would be 15, the number of the sample 105 and the event would be 1, 2 and 3. But it seems its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that exactly 3 seats will be unused is:

$$\binom{105}{95}0.85^{95}0.15^{10}$$